# @Theme annotation is ignored

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I use the Theme annotation in a class extending AppShellConfigurator ar required.
@Theme(value="Material") is my annotation.
However I can write anything in the value, also meaningless values but is ignored : I allways see Lumo theme.
I also tried to set the variant DARK of the lumo theme but still is ignored.
My version is 23.3.21.
What's wrong ?
Tks

P.S. : also @JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/presets/compact.js") seems to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/styling/advanced/material-theme):

```
@Theme(themeClass = Material.class, variant = Material.DARK)
public class AppShell implements AppShellConfigurator {
}
```

Comment: I already tested this solution but nothing changed.
Tks

Comment: Remember to do `mvn clean vaadin:clean-frontend`? What server/jvm are you running? This is from a working maven-jetty project and I tested also with 23.3.21.

Comment: I use tomcat with a 11 jvm from amazon

Comment: done clean-frontend but nothing changed.

Comment: Should be fairly standard. I guess you have tested with any other change in AppShell.java to see that it actually loads the app classes correctly.

Comment: The AppsShellConfigurator class is istantiated and the only method configure is called, what can I verify ?

Comment: PageTitle works fine.

Comment: Ok. That sound like the problem might not be here at all. Maybe the ignored module is a hint?